# How can i process json data in an excel file to make it clearly visible?

Tags: python, json, excel

I used a python script to convert json data into an Excel file. The problem is that one of the columns contains dictionaries and as a result the data is not displayed in nice rows and columns. I used this python script to change it.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

' Replace 'your_file.xlsx' with the actual path to your Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('file_data_columns_split.xlsx')

' Assuming the JSON data is stored in a column named 'conversations'
' Use the 'json.loads()' function to convert the JSON strings to Python dictionaries
df['conversations'] = df['conversations'].apply(json.loads)

' Assuming te JSON data contains nested dictionaries and you want to split them into separate '  ' ' columns
' Use the 'pandas.json_normalize()' function
df_normalized = pd.json_normalize(df['conversations'])

' Merge the normalized data with the original DataFrame
df = pd.concat([df, df_normalized], axis=1)

print(df)
or
display(df)
```

i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Maarerdink/Desktop/file_data_columns_split.py", line 9, in <module>
    df['conversations'] = df['conversations'].apply(json.loads)
  File "C:\Users\Maarteerdink\Desktop\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4630, in apply
    return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
  File "C:\Users\Maardink\Desktop\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1025, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Users\Maardink\Desktop\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1076, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2834, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\Users\Maaerdink\Desktop\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Maartdink\Desktop\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Madink\Desktop\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

How can i solve this?

I read the traceback that states the specific lines of code were the problem occurs. Apparently it has to do with the fact that certain json data in line 1 column 2 (char 1) is not between double quotes. I added double quotes in the Excel file to this string but when i rerun the script i get the same error message.